# Jogl, display() gets called before init() finishes

Tags: jogl, opengl-4

First time I have this problem

This is the [last line](http://%20https://github.com/elect86/NvGlSamples/blob/master/NvGlSamples/src/nvGlSamples/bindlessApp/BindlessApp.java#L200) executed in the `init()`

and then `display()` is called

Never faced this problem before. It quits `init()` at the same point even debugging step by step..

Ps: using `com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator as animator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an exception in the `init()` I wasnt catching before